# ms sql: How to use Dense_Rank in conjunction with a Group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, row-number

I have tried to find some records with a common table expression and in conjunction with a group by to find duplicateNo and subDuplicateNo of a specific table. Its all about finding duplicates from a table with a notification of duplicateNo and subDuplicateNo.
But I'm wondering that subDuplicateNo always are 1. But how can I increment the column subDuplicateNo? I have until now searched a lot without any success :-(

My code is as below:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, t.Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, t.Telefon, Upper_postnr, Count(*) AS occurences,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, t.Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, t.Telefon, Upper_postnr) as dubletno, t.subdubletno
    FROM (
        SELECT V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr ORDER BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr) AS subdubletno
        FROM Medlemsdata V2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Postnumre
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN MedlemsAdresse MA2 ON Postnumre.Postnummer = MA2.Postnr ON V2.FK_AdrID = MA2.AdrID
        WHERE V2.vennenr > 0 AND V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart <> '' AND V2.Upper_Efternavn <> '' AND Upper_Adresse <> '' AND V2.Telefon <> '' AND Upper_postnr <> ''

    ) as t
    GROUP BY t.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr, t.subdubletno
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
)

SELECT V1.Vennenr, V1.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V1.Upper_Efternavn, MA1.Upper_Adresse, V1.Telefon, MA1.Upper_postnr, cte.dubletno, cte.subdubletno
FROM 
    Medlemsdata V1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Postnumre
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN MedlemsAdresse MA1 ON Postnumre.Postnummer = MA1.Postnr ON V1.FK_AdrID = MA1.AdrID
    INNER JOIN cte ON 
        cte.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart = V1.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart AND 
        cte.Upper_Efternavn = v1.Upper_Efternavn AND
        cte.Upper_Adresse = MA1.Upper_Adresse AND
        cte.Upper_postnr = MA1.Upper_postnr AND
        cte.Telefon = V1.Telefon
WHERE V1.vennenr > 0 and cte.occurences > 1
```

and the actual and the expected data are as follows:

```
Actual result:

ID       Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart  UPPER_EFTERNAVN  UPPER_ADRESSE  TELEFON   UPPER_POSTNR  DubletNo  SubDubletNo
===============================================================================================================
1        ANNE                     JENSEN           BIRKEHAVEN 2   12345678  7100          1         1
2        ANNE                     JENSEN           BIRKEHAVEN 2   12345678  7100          1         1
3        TOM                      HANSEN           SLOTSGADE 1    98765432  6000          2         1
4        TOM                      HANSEN           SLOTSGADE 1    98765432  6000          2         1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Expected result:

ID       Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart  UPPER_EFTERNAVN  UPPER_ADRESSE  TELEFON   UPPER_POSTNR  DubletNo  SubDubletNo
===============================================================================================================
1        ANNE                     JENSEN           BIRKEHAVEN 2   12345678  7100          1         1
2        ANNE                     JENSEN           BIRKEHAVEN 2   12345678  7100          1         2
3        TOM                      HANSEN           SLOTSGADE 1    98765432  6000          2         1
4        TOM                      HANSEN           SLOTSGADE 1    98765432  6000          2         2
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.
 I really hope that this technically can be done ...
Regards
Michael

**Update**:
I have tried the following code - but now it gives me 1 in all records of both duplicateNo and subDuplicateNo :-(

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, t.Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, t.Telefon, Upper_postnr, t.dubletno, t.subdubletno
    FROM (
        SELECT V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, v2.Telefon, Upper_postnr) as occurences,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr ORDER BY Upper_postnr) AS dubletno,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr ORDER BY Upper_postnr) AS subdubletno
        FROM Medlemsdata V2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Postnumre
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN MedlemsAdresse MA2 ON Postnumre.Postnummer = MA2.Postnr ON V2.FK_AdrID = MA2.AdrID
        WHERE V2.vennenr > 0 AND V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart <> '' AND V2.Upper_Efternavn <> '' AND Upper_Adresse <> '' AND V2.Telefon <> '' AND Upper_postnr <> ''
        GROUP BY Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, Upper_Efternavn, Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr
        HAVING Count(*) > 1
    ) as t
)

SELECT V1.Vennenr, V1.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V1.Upper_Efternavn, MA1.Upper_Adresse, V1.Telefon, MA1.Upper_postnr, cte.dubletno, cte.subdubletno
FROM 
    Medlemsdata V1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Postnumre
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN MedlemsAdresse MA1 ON Postnumre.Postnummer = MA1.Postnr ON V1.FK_AdrID = MA1.AdrID
    INNER JOIN cte ON 
        cte.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart = V1.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart AND 
        cte.Upper_Efternavn = v1.Upper_Efternavn AND
        cte.Upper_Adresse = MA1.Upper_Adresse AND
        cte.Upper_postnr = MA1.Upper_postnr AND
        cte.Telefon = V1.Telefon
WHERE V1.vennenr > 0
```

Comment: Isn't this always going to evaluate to 1?: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr ORDER BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, MA2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr) AS subdubletno` The columns being ordered are all in the same partition.

Comment: Also I'm pretty confident your query doesn't need to be nearly that complicated.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks for commenting - but I would like to do all the searching after duplicates in one sql, so thats why I have tried to do it in that way

Comment: When you use a `group by` and then an analytic function with the same partitions there's only going to be a single row.

Comment: @shawnt00 Does that mean that it technically can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query appears to be doing a lot of extra work. I also suspect your right join construction could be simplified.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, V2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, V2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr) as occurences,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, V2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr) as dubletno,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart, V2.Upper_Efternavn, V2.Upper_Adresse, Telefon, Upper_postnr ORDER BY Upper_postnr) AS subdubletno
    FROM data V2
    WHERE V2.vennenr > 0 AND V2.Upper_Fornavn_FirstPart <> '' AND V2.Upper_Efternavn <> '' AND Upper_Adresse <> '' AND V2.Telefon <> '' AND Upper_postnr <> ''
) as t
WHERE t.occurences > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for rewriting my code - but I can see that ```COUNT()``` must have a parameter to be executed - but I don't know what the parameter must be :-( Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MichaelEriksen Sorry, just `count(*)`.

Comment: @MichaelEriksen I see your updated question. What was the result of running the query in my answer?

Comment: Yes that was the result of the code you suggested...

Comment: @MichaelEriksen My answer is the entire query. It not just a replacement for the CTE.

Comment: Thanks for helping :-) I have now tried the query alone - but it gives me to much results :-( And duplicateNo=1 and supDuplicateNo=1 for all records :-(

Comment: @MichaelEriksen I made a tweak to the `DENSE_RANK` expression. But based on the sample data above my query appears to work. https://rextester.com/NDHQU90625